# Spotfire reports reloading instead of running from cache

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have a report configured for caching via Scheduled Updates. The caching appears to complete after about 2 hours, but when I try to run the report (and I've double-checked that I'm trying to run it from the same location that the scheduled update references), it begins trying to load the entire dataset instead of pulling from the cache. Any suggestions on what might be causing spotfire to ignore the cached data set?

Comment: Can you add an image of what your scheduling rule looks like, or add specifics here. If it runs for two hours, but the rule is not set to be active for longer than that, cache will be dropped and it will reload.

Comment: also what version of Spotfire are you using?

Comment: We are using spotfire 7.7. I looked at the rule and found I had no schedule, but my intent was to just reload the cache as needed. I added a schedule to it (as maybe the schedule is more to define how long the cache is valid?) and started a reload.

Comment: This is confusing. The schedule will tell you how long the cache is valid for, when to start loading, and how often to reload. It is not a device to say "only cache between these hours, then don't cache any more but hold the results". If you want your cache to be valid, you must have that schedule set up for the hours you want cache available. Outside of those hours, it will reload.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the lack of a schedule on the rule. Thank you to Mark P. for directing me to the schedules and explaining how they work!